# creating php cli processes running in background

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line-interface, sh

I am looking to run 10 php CLI processes (parallel) using one shell script. but, I am trying to find out how to send a process to background once created.

something like this I am trying. any help will be appreciated. (just the flow, not a real shell script)

`for loop 1 to 10 

               php -q /home/xxx/xxx.php &     // I want to send this to background one created. because it runs indefintely depending on the task it needs to do.

end for`

sorry, I had the hard time with this.

Comment: `cmd &` will run `cmd` as a background job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly,

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    php -q /home/xxx/xxx.php &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Supervisord for scripts like this. It's has a simple configuration file and you just need to set script path and processes count.